# How do I properly send a jquery post request with JSON data to MVC 3 such that it yields control back to my controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I know this is probably a common and easily answered question, but I'm a nub. Here's my situation:

I have a list of complex objects that I can send just fine using an ajax call as follows:

```
$j.ajax({
    url: actionURL,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataToSend,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

The MVC3 Controller action at "actionURL" gets the object and automatically deserializes it to the object I want.  However, when I return an ActionResult from that controller function, nothing happens.  I want to regain control in this  controller function and return a "PostResults" view defined in cshtml just like I do in every other controller function, but it seems like my return is returning to JS.   I am guessing the answer has something to do with routing, but as I said I'm a nub.

Any idea why the JS ajax call seems to be taking control of the flow, and how to stop this from happening?  I want this JS module to just act like every other view I have!

Comment: what does your controller action method look like?

Comment: Simply `PostTestResults(TestResults tr) { return View(tr); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a post-redirect. Find out more info [Here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-can-i-do-a-form-post-w-a-location-redirect).

The true purpose of ajax is to actually NOT leave the current page user is viewing, thus creating a more responsive and fast UI.

Comment: Right, I want to do a full new page in this case so the jquery ajax stuff seems to not be the answer, thanks.

Comment: No problem, you can find more info on the link, as well as solutions created by others. This is kind of 'highjacking' of ajax. As always, mark as answer and/or vote the replies you find helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question and a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293067/how-do-i-properly-send-a-jquery-post-request-with-json-data-to-mvc-3-such-that-i)

However, you should also think whether you really need a full reload or would it be better to return a partial page in the result and then "success" function updates a portion of the page accordingly.

Comment: In this case, I do want a full new page.  A test has been run and now the data is being returned and a whole new view is being shown where the data can be viewed and manipulated.  Thanks!